# Parse multiple values and store [ANDROID]

Tags: android, xml, parsing

I would like to parse a webservice response in xml on my android.

The way most "easy" what I did was this:

```
public String valor;

public static FormasDePagamento[] parseXML(String xml)
    throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
    InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(is);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    FormasDePagamento[] formas = new FormasDePagamento[7];
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        formas[i] = new FormasDePagamento();
        formas[i].valor = doc.getElementsByTagName("VALOR").item(i)
                .getTextContent();
}
```

But now what I need is to get all that are in the result (which can be 7, but can also be 500 results) and in addition, each store a list to be displayed as a list in activity.

How can I develop this? Thank U!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your obtained list to an `ArrayAdapter` and show it on a `ListView`

```
ArrayAdapter<FormaDePagamento> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<FormaDePagamento>(context,android.R.layout_simple_list_item_1,parseXML(xml));
yourListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

`ArrayAdapter` gets the `toString()` of your class, so remember to override it to show whatever info you want